# Read .txt into a matrix

Tags: c, file, matrix

Ive been trying to get the numbers from a text file into a matrix.
The matrix is static and [50][50], but im currently stuck with this code since the output is always 0.

```
int main() {
    int mat[50][50], i, j;

    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("teste.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
            if (!fscanf(file, "%lf", &mat[i][j]))
                break;
            printf("%d\n", mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    int a;
}
```

Comment: Your description says the matrix is 30X30 but your code is reading a 50X50 matrix

Comment: Did you really name your file `teste.txt`, and not `test.txt`?

Comment: @eduffy: `teste` is German *and* Portuguese for `test`.

Comment: Anyway, this may need a space in the `fscanf` format string. (If the numbers are space separated, that is. We don't know.)

Answer (score 2):

The [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) format string should be `%d` or `%i` to read into an `int` or alternatively, declare `mat` as a matrix of `double` values.

The `break` statement won't do the error recovery that you need. It will simply exit the inner loop.

P.S. Use a `const` for the array dimension rather than repeating `50` several times in the code. (DRY.)